# Sorting listview using combobox

Tags: vb.net, listview, sorting

How can I sort a listview value by using external components? Which mean, user not click on header of listview, but selecting the combobox value which serve a certain header that user can sort. I have around 6 column in listview. I just need to sort this listview by selecting combobox and I will write a code to sort the listview based from combobox1.text value.. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a class that implements System.Collection.IComparer, 
and have your comparison rules based on your dropdown value.
then you need to set the listview ListViewItemSorter property with an instance of the comparer you wrote, and call it's Sort method.

Comment: if so,then it is much complicated than set the header to be clickable right? Which I mean that I can code inside the listview function rather than I create a class of IComparer as I seen the result of my question mostly in internet. I wish there is more easier to control within the function. Thanks man

Comment: Implementing the IComparer interface is very easy. It only has a single method called Compare, that returns an integer between -1 and 1. then all you have to do is call the sort method that is already implemented by the nice guys at Microsoft. definitely easier then writing the sort yourself...

Of course, setting the list header clickable is even easier then that :-)

Answer (score 0):

I finally found some answer for my question. And what I have to do is create another class for IComparer as @zohar suggest in my comment. Please find my answer below:
My listview name is lvshop.

At top of the class, declare this:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Collections
```

Within class, declare this:

```
Private m_SortingColumn As ColumnHeader
```

At windows load, I create a column header:

```
lvShop.View = View.Details
lvShop.Columns.Add("Shop No", 70, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
lvShop.Columns.Add("Shop Name", 170, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
lvShop.Columns.Add("Shop Details", 500, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
lvShop.Columns.Add("Category", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
lvShop.Columns.Add("Website", 170, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
lvShop.Columns.Add("Phone No", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
```

At listview event

```
Private Sub lvShop_ColumnClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ColumnClickEventArgs) Handles lvShop.ColumnClick
     Dim new_sorting_column As ColumnHeader = lvShop.Columns(e.Column)
     Try
              ' Figure out the new sorting order.
              Dim sort_order As System.Windows.Forms.SortOrder
              If m_SortingColumn Is Nothing Then
                  ' New column. Sort ascending.
                  sort_order = SortOrder.Ascending
              Else
              ' See if this is the same column.
              If new_sorting_column.Equals(m_SortingColumn) Then
                  ' Same column. Switch the sort order.
                  If m_SortingColumn.Text.StartsWith("> ") Then
                      sort_order = SortOrder.Descending
                  Else
                      sort_order = SortOrder.Ascending
                  End If
              Else
                  ' New column. Sort ascending.
                  sort_order = SortOrder.Ascending
              End If
              ' Remove the old sort indicator.
              m_SortingColumn.Text = _
              m_SortingColumn.Text.Substring(2)
         End If
         ' Display the new sort order.
         m_SortingColumn = new_sorting_column
         If sort_order = SortOrder.Ascending Then
              m_SortingColumn.Text = "> " & m_SortingColumn.Text
         Else
              m_SortingColumn.Text = "< " & m_SortingColumn.Text
         End If
         ' Create a comparer.
         lvShop.ListViewItemSorter = New ListViewColumnSorter(e.Column, sort_order)
         ' Sort.
         lvShop.Sort()
     Catch ex As Exception
         strErrMsg = "Oops! Something is wrong with sorting column header."
         MessageBox.Show(strErrMsg & vbCrLf & "Err: " & ex.Message)
     End Try
End Sub
```

Create a new class within the project with name `ListViewColumnSorter`
Copy this and paste to the class.

```
Imports System.Collections
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class ListViewColumnSorter
    Implements IComparer

    Private m_ColumnNumber As Integer
    Private m_SortOrder As SortOrder

    Public Sub New(ByVal column_number As Integer, ByVal _
        sort_order As SortOrder)
        m_ColumnNumber = column_number
        m_SortOrder = sort_order
    End Sub

    ' Compare the items in the appropriate column
    ' for objects x and y.
    Public Function Compare(ByVal x As Object, ByVal y As _
        Object) As Integer Implements _
        System.Collections.IComparer.Compare
        Dim item_x As ListViewItem = DirectCast(x,  _
            ListViewItem)
        Dim item_y As ListViewItem = DirectCast(y,  _
            ListViewItem)

        ' Get the sub-item values.
        Dim string_x As String
        If item_x.SubItems.Count <= m_ColumnNumber Then
            string_x = ""
        Else
            string_x = item_x.SubItems(m_ColumnNumber).Text
        End If

        Dim string_y As String
        If item_y.SubItems.Count <= m_ColumnNumber Then
            string_y = ""
        Else
            string_y = item_y.SubItems(m_ColumnNumber).Text
        End If

        ' Compare them.
        If m_SortOrder = SortOrder.Ascending Then
            If IsNumeric(string_x) And IsNumeric(string_y) _
                Then
                Return Val(string_x).CompareTo(Val(string_y))
            ElseIf IsDate(string_x) And IsDate(string_y) _
                Then
                Return DateTime.Parse(string_x).CompareTo(DateTime.Parse(string_y))
            Else
                Return String.Compare(string_x, string_y)
            End If
        Else
            If IsNumeric(string_x) And IsNumeric(string_y) _
                Then
                Return Val(string_y).CompareTo(Val(string_x))
            ElseIf IsDate(string_x) And IsDate(string_y) _
                Then
                Return DateTime.Parse(string_y).CompareTo(DateTime.Parse(string_x))
            Else
                Return String.Compare(string_y, string_x)
            End If
        End If
    End Function
End Class
```

This sorting will sort all column in your listview. Thanks to the internet for connecting programmer :)